# Passing a double value into another activity,then sum it with another double value in android

Tags: android

I am new in Android development. I want to take a user input as a double value and then pass it to the next activity, and then sum it with another value, but I am having trouble passing it. 
I checked for a solution in this site, but it's really not helping... so help me if you can, thanks in advance :)
Here is my code:

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
TextView textView;
EditText userEditText;
Button  goButton;
//MainActivity result=new MainActivity();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    userEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    goButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    goButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String s1 = userEditText.getText().toString();
            double firstDouble = Double.parseDouble(s1);

            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            Bundle b= new Bundle();
            b.putDouble("FIRST", firstDouble);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: you will need to do getIntent().getExtras() in the other activity, which will give you a bundle. Then your value will be in the bundle

Comment: `MainActivity` looks fine, show us the code of `SecondActicity`.

Comment: addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    String s2 = secondEditText.getText().toString();
    double secondDouble=Double.parseDouble(s2);
   
    Intent secondIntent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this, LastActivity.class);
    secondIntent.putExtra("SECOND_NUMBER",secondDouble );
    

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    double result = b.getDouble("FIRST");
    double newResultDouble;
    
    newResultDouble=secondDouble+result;
   
    startActivity(secondIntent);}});

Comment: Did u find any problem in my SecondActivity?